# Multiple parameters of a function

Tags: function, haskell, parameters, arguments, fold

How to give

```
break (== ' ') xxs
```

multiple boolean parameters without changing the definition? Or that is inevitable. For instance

```
break (== (' ' || '\t' || '\n')) xss
```

`foldl` and `foldr` are one way, but here they are not applicable, or at least I haven't been able to use them.

Comment: `break (flip elem " \t\n")`?

Comment: You can give `break` any function for its first argument. So you could just make a new function that is the predicate that you want and pass that to `break`.

Comment: @Zeta Yes, it works, but could you explain it a little?

Comment: `elem`checks if something is in a list so this will check if the argument is either `'\t'` or `'\n'` (a string is a list of chars) - now as `elem` wants it's arguments in the wrong order Zeta had to `flip` the function first

Comment: @Carsten: I wanted to use \`elem\`, but that doesn't really work in comments :/.

Comment: @Zeta You can write ``(`elem` " \t\n")`` if you surround it with double backticks. Roughly, two groups of N consecutive backticks can enclose any expression which uses only at most N-1 consecutive backticks. (SO should document this better, IMHO)

Comment: I actually quite like defining a function along the lines of `(<>) = liftM2 (||)` so you can do `break ((== ' ') <> (== '\t') <> (== '\n')) xss`

Comment: See also: `Data.Char.isSpace`, `Prelude.words`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
break (\x -> x == ' ' || x == '\t' || x == '\n') xss
```

Comment: This answer is great because it is right at the OP's level and opens up a new world without overexplaining.

Answer (score 5):

Your current question isn't really about multiple parameters, but different predicates for `break`. Let's consider `break`'s type for a second:

```
break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

This type of function `(a -> Bool)` is called a *predicate*. You can use anything that uses the right `a` and returns a `Bool`. That's why your first code typechecks:

```
ghci> :t (== ' ')
(== ' ') :: Char -> Bool
```

Now, if you want to use several characters as possible break symbols, you need to use another `Char -> Bool`. If the characters are fixed (and you don't have many of them), you can use a list `[Char]` and `elem`:

```
yourCharacters = [' ','\t','\n'] 

predicate :: Char -> Bool
predicate c = c `elem` yourCharacters
```

We can use this as predicate for `break`:

```
myBreak = break (`elem` yourCharacters)
```

At this point, you could also change `myBreak` so that it takes a list of characters, at which point you'll get:

```
myBreak' :: [Char] -> [Char] -> ([Char], [Char])
myBreak' limiters = break (`elem` limiters)
-- myBreak' limiters str = break (`elem` limiters) str
```

HTH